# How to get logs in Cloudwatch for all ECS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have problems to get logs from all my ECS instances, that are started by a task in my cluster.
I followed this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html

I get logs for one instance, but if I try to run 2, with auto-scaling group, I don't see the logs of the second instance.

I also tried to configure the cloudwatch agent in my docker image, but I don't see any improvements.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If one ECS task is logging fine, then increasing that to two should not break logging in any way. Each ECS task will log to a separate log stream inside the log group. Are you sure you are checking for new log streams?

Comment: That is my guess, but I just see one log stream inside my log group, and I clicked refresh button more than necessary :)  If I restart the instances, I also see a new logstream created.

Answer (score 2):

Using driver with [awslogs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/) is the best way to manage your logs when a container is created by ecs.
Every time a new task is created by ECs, a new log-stram is generated with that task's name and is made available in the cloudwatch log group.

Comment: Right, my mistake was to expect a log for an ecs instance when it is actually generated when the task is started, so an instance itself could logs things, but that was not the kind of logs I was looking for.